# Using RaphaelJS; Create 'paper' at global level - I can create multiple papers, but can't .remove them

Tags: javascript, raphael

I created this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/andrewgehring/BjMzH/2/embedded/result/)

The remove function doesn't work, and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong...

any, and all, help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This works](http://jsfiddle.net/e5Lkk/).

In short, you are missing a `return` statement and you were wrongly using your variables.

Comment: Thank you!, The wrong variables were a "typo" while inputting to Fiddle, but the 'return' fixed it!